# treeview ajax control

Tags: jquery, ajax, treeview

Am working with `jquery.treeview` control in a jsp page. It's working as follows.

From the very first time, when the page loads server side call will load a list of data -something like the whole data under a huge database.
And using the treeview control it will create a treeview on the page. Here the problem is the list from the server side is very huge, so that when writing that on to the page, it gets stucked and around 10-12 times am getting a dialogue box that will say the jquery.js file is busy, so do you want to continue or stop script?

So i need a solution -like -for the very first time i need to load only the outermost nodes - means my server side list will contains only the parent elements - say databases for the time being. And when at the time of clicking on a particular database, an ajax call will gone, which will load its child elements -say tables.

I think if we can able to load the treeview in this way, i can avoid the problem of page getting stucked with huge list.

I searched for a better ajax treeview like control a lot, but can't find a better one that suitable for my problem.?

Can anyone provide a better solution for this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/treeview_suppliment.htm) an example of an asynchronous treeview using `jQuery.treeview`. The server - side is written in php, but the idea is completely transposable to any language.